# django rest-framework serializer reverse relation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, reverse, relation, serialization

I am programming django based web site using django rest-framework.
I want to use rest-framework to get model's data.

this is my model.py

```
class TimeTable(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    credit = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, default='2018')
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_code + '-' + self.subject_name

class Class(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True)
    timetable = models.ForeignKey(TimeTable, null=True)
    grade = models.FloatField()
```

this is serializer.py

```
class TimeTableSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeTable
        fields = ('url', 'subject_name', 'subject_code', 'classification', 'professor', 'department', 'credit', 'year', 'semester')

class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    timetables = TimeTableSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ('url','owner', 'timetable', 'grade', 'timetables')
```

I want to get JSON response Like this 
(http://localhost:8000/api/classes/)

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/classes/8/",
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/profiles/19/",
        "timetable": "http://localhost:8000/api/timetables/3/",
        "grade": 4.5
        "timetables": {
                          "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/timetables/3/",
                          "subject_name": "Artificial Inteligence",
                          "subject_code": "3413513413",
                          "classification": "major",
                          "professor": "John Lee",
                          "department": "software",
                          "credit": "3",
                          "year": "2018",
                          "semester": "1"
                      }
    }
]
```

but i got this

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/classes/8/",
        "owner": "http://localhost:8000/api/profiles/19/",
        "timetable": "http://localhost:8000/api/timetables/3/",
        "grade": 4.5
    }
]
```

How Can I get TimeTable's JSON data in Class JSON??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    timetable = TimeTableSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ('url','owner', 'timetable', 'grade')
```

Comment: thanx for your kindness, but i got this error
    Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `timetables` on serializer `ClassSerializer`.
    The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any 
    attribute or key on the `Class` instance.
    Original exception text was: 'Class' object has no attribute 'timetables'.

Comment: i tried, but i got error.
The field 'timetables' was declared on serializer ClassSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

Comment: check the name i have used, its timetable for TimeTableSerializer

Comment: finally, i solved it! thanx a lot!!!!
i think,
timetable = TimeTableSerializer(read_only=True)
was right code.

Comment: but if i use many=True,  type error ('TimeTable' object is not iterable)